# Angular 2+ share data between a component and router-outlet

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I want to pass data/variables from a component to other components build with router-outlet. I have to use EventEmitter.

This is the structure of the app:

```
<iber-page-top (parqueEmisor)="getParkId($event)"></iber-page-top>
<aside class="iber-sidebar">
    <iber-menu></iber-menu>
</aside>
<div class="iber-main">
    <div class="iber-container">    
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

It has to be from iber-page-top to router-outlet.

I have tried a few tutorial that worked fine passing data from a child component to the parent one, but its a bit different.

I´d appreciate a bit of help, I am very lost!!!.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't possible (from what I know). If you want routed components to communicate, you will have to use a sharing service.

Comment: Thank very much!! :)

Comment: No problem, and since it is in the documentation, consider removing your question !